# Show Timer while playing video using react-native-video

Tags: react-native, duration, react-native-video

I have a requirement in my project to show timer when the video is playing. I know there are libraries available for this in React Native, but my requirement is to show the Timer below the video player. As the video  progresses the time should decrease till the video gets finish. Please help me.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I solved it by myself.

I just used the following approach:

```
<Video
          resizeMode={'contain'}
          style={{ height: 312 }}
          url={url}
          placeholder={"https://baconmockup.com/300/200/"}
          onProgress={e => this.progress(e)}
          ref={(ref) => { this.video = ref }}
        />

progress(e) {
    console.warn('Time' + parseInt(e.currentTime))
  }
```

I am using react-native-af-video-player and onProgress solved my purpose which is provided by react-native-video.